# Emojis in Pycharm Windows 7

Tags: python, pycharm

I am making a program in Python using Pycharm IDE and I need Emoji packages in it.  I have seen some guys do it in Mac using Ctrl + Space, How I can do this in windows ?

[image]

Comment: Try using https://pypi.org/project/emoji/

Answer (score 10):

It's a new feature in Windows 10. You can access the emoji keyboard shortcut using the keys:
**"Windows key + ." or, "Windows key + >"**

The **"."** is the **period** or, the **full stop** key, not the point or the decimal key.

Comment: What is it in Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 3):

In windows 10 you can use `windows key + .(dot)` or `windows key + ;`

Answer (score 3):

Use either of these keyboard shortcuts:

- Windows Key and Period / Full Stop Key ( . )
- Windows Key and Semicolon Key ( ; )

An emoji picker will appear on screen over the text field:

In other words, hold the **Windows** key down and press either the **period (.)** or **semicolon (;)** key.

Your cursor must be somewhere that can accept text while pressing these keys, but you can use this shortcut in any application, from text fields in your web browser to messaging apps to Notepad to Microsoft Word.

You have to just click the emoji in the window that pops up to insert it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is an alternative way to use emoji in windows, it works for me, You 
   can try this.

[image]

You have to use Unicode for your specific emoji.
   Here I am sharing a link that contains the Unicode chart. 
   (https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).

- At first copy Unicode.     *Ex:-->*   For **":)"** Unicode: **U+1F600**
- Add 3 (zero's) 0 in the place of +   *Ex:-->*  **"U0001F600"**
- Add a \ (backslash) in front of the code. *Ex:-->*  **"\U0001F600"**

  ```
    emojis={
        ":)": "\U0001F600",

        ":D": "\U0001F603"
     }
  ```

Comment: I had the smiley for ":D": "\U0001F603", but get a square for ":)": "\U0001F600". I have Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu   <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>  opens an emoji picker window on Jetbrains IDE's , check this out this may work on windows too

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugin on Pycharm : https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9174-emoji-support-plugin

It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Adding for `macOS` as well, its <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

This command is not just for PyCharm, it will work on other applications as well, in macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any shortcut just go to this direction menu:

```
edit --> Emojis & symbols
```

Answer (score -2):

It is include in Mac OS, I do not think you can do that in Windows.

Comment: "I do not think..". Is that answer ?

Comment: Well I am pretty sure, but maybe there is a software I don't know that allows it.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the `Windows + ;` key combination to open that box, however the emojis won't appear as bright as they do in mac.